# problem with elementorFrontend hooks. Manually created widget is not displayed on the frontend page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, elementor

I created a custom widget. Each widget has its own php and js files that are interconnected. When I call the widget in the Elementor editor it is properly displayed and everything is fine. When I update the changes and open the page the widget is not showing.
I placed this code in the js file, but it doesn't seem to load on the frontend.

`elementorFrontend.hooks.addAction( 'frontend/element_ready/MonthlyReturnTable.default', function( $scope ) {
console.log('Inner', $scope);

```
    if ($scope.find( 'div')) {
       const title = $scope.find('div')[2].getAttribute("data-title");
       
       ReactDOM.render(<MonthlyReturnTable selectedColumns={selectedColumns} title={title}  />, $scope.find( 'div' )[1]);

}
```

});`

when I open the page my console is empty, the elementorFrontend function does not work.
Can you help me?
is there another way to display the widget on the frontend?

I created a custom widget in one php file. All additional functions are executed in its js file (these two files are related to each other).
in the js file after all the necessary checks and data filters, I need to display the widget on the page. Above in the example, I attached the code that is in the js file.
I tried to use all the elementor functions to display the widget in this way, I also tried to add a set time out but no luck.
at no point did I get the response in the console that was indicated within the elementorfrontend function.
I just need to display the widget on the page.